# how to find cell that does not contain particular text and show it's value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i will like to check which formula will work by checking the selected cell `F2:M2` that does not contain the world `Not` and show the value of the cell in `N2`

any suggestion are appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array formula (entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter) will give you the correct heading

```
{=INDEX($F$1:$M$1, 0, MATCH(1, IF(LOWER(LEFT($F$2:$M$2, 3))<>"not", 1, 0), 0))}
```

I believe you meant N2, not N1 thought.

Comment: Thanks V.B. for the reply.
i got #VALUE! instead

Comment: As @Jerry said, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter while entering the formula. His answer is equivalent to mine besides some logic difference within MATCH(...)

Comment: When you compare text with comparison operators like <> or = it's not case-sensitive (e.g. this formula  ="NOT"="not" returns TRUE) so you don't really need LOWER function here

Comment: @barryhoudini have been working in C# much more than in Excel lately so the habit, thanks for the comment! By the way, how to do case sensitive comparison in Excel with built-in functions? - I have never needed this over the past 10+ years I am using Excel, but just wondering...

Comment: @V.B. You might try case sensitive comparison with `=EXACT(string1, string2)`

Comment: FIND is also case-sensitive so in Jerry's formula if you replace SEARCH with FIND you get a case-sensitive version

Comment: @barryhoudini I used FIND now and then, never thought that differs from SEARCH. Now I see that FIND's tooltip says that it is case sensitive. Endless opportunities to excel in Excel!

Comment: FIND also differs from SEARCH in that it doesn't accept wildcards, you can use `=SEARCH("x*y",A1)` with * acting as a wildcard but if you change to FIND the * is treated as a literal asterisk

Comment: @barryhoudini usually if you have to do such complicated things like wildcard match in Excel spreadsheet, you have problems with bad data organization. If I control everything, I could process data in Access (at least) which is much more efficient. If I have to deal with someone else's Excel file in limited lime and it is ad hoc task, I could through VBA to the task. Anyway, thanks a lot for the tips! Hope they could let me avoid VBA some time in the future :)

Comment: I agree - I don't think I've ever **needed** to use SEARCH with a wildcard

Answer (score 2):

You mean in range F2:M2? The formula I came up with uses `SEARCH()` for this, with some other function, namely `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `IFERROR` like so:

```
=INDEX(F2:M2,0,MATCH(0,IFERROR(SEARCH("*not*",F2:M2),0),0))
```

This is an array formula, and hence will work properly if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

EDIT: Oops, no need for the wildcards:

```
=INDEX(F2:M2,0,MATCH(0,IFERROR(SEARCH("not",F2:M2),0),0))
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry for the reply.
i got #N/A

Comment: @Desmond As mentioned in my answer, instead of using Enter, you need to hold down Ctrl and Shift and then press Enter. I know it's a bit confusing at first, but that's how it works!

Comment: By the way, those are called array functions. They return multiple results in a single cell (you can check it by clicking in the formula bar containing the formula and press F9) and thus, excel will display #n/a for array formulae.

Comment: @Desmond I hope it helped :)

Comment: +1 - Note: you don't need the wildcards in the SEARCH function, the function works on a "contains" basis anyway......

Comment: @barryhoudini Shows I'm not that all familiar with SEARCH ^^; Thank you Barry! ^^